# Where I can find ModSecurity Rules for Specific Applications

Tags: security, web-server, web-hosting, mod-security

Where I can find ModSecurity Rules for Specific Applications specially joomla, wordpress, mambo ?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the website for ModSecurity?

Comment: What kind of rules are you looking for?

Comment: anything to reduce any attack on famous cms !! rules for sql injection, xss etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OWASP Core Ruleset](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_ModSecurity_Core_Rule_Set_Project) contains a set called [`slr_rules`](http://mod-security.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mod-security/crs/trunk/slr_rules/) which are created by SpiderLabs Research to protect against known vulnerabilities.  These rules are not activated in the default configuration.

There are separate files for PHPBB, Joomla and Wordpress as well as files covering XSS, RFI, LFI and SQL attacks in these and many other popular web applications.  Mambo is included in this list.

Many of the rules have an identifier included that can tell you where the vulnerability was announced and/or documented.  The tags appear like this:

```
tag:'bugtraq,33103'
tag:'url,www.milw0rm.com/exploits/4026'
tag:'url,www.securityfocus.com/bid/36741/'
tag:'cve,CVE-2007-2825'
tag:'url,www.inliniac.net/blog/?p=71'
tag:'url,www.osvdb.org/34164'
tag:'url,www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_File_Inclusion'
```

Trustwave also publish lots of interesting research on the [SpiderLabs blog](http://blog.spiderlabs.com) and this often includes `mod_security` rules for blocking specific threats they have detected hitting their honeypots.

You might also have some luck looking in the forums and bug tracking databases of the web applications in question.  They are the people with the best incentive to create `mod_security` rules for their own applications.